# How Compare two folders, replace different files and add new files if not exist (.yml, cpanel)

Tags: python, yaml

I try to make **.yml** file for **cpanel**.
This file is push along with website repository and should automatically check each time the names of the folders(subfolders) and files and their size match (but not the last change date, because the uploaded files are always have newer date but may not different content inside).
If a file from folder A (**/repository/www**) is different size from the same file in folder B (**/public_html/www**) it must replace the file in folder B with the one from folder A. Also, if there is a file in folder B that does not exist in folder A, it should be deleted.
The idea is to always have the files on the **/public_html/www** (folder B) identical to those of the last uploaded **repository/www** (folder A).
Since I have never worked with a python, I only managed to write such a script:

---- This when replace all files -----

```
---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/user/public_html/www/
    - /bin/cp -r www $DEPLOYPATH
```

----- This when replace only couple files -----

```
---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/user/public_html/www/data/
    - /bin/cp www/data/FileA.json $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/cp www/data/FileB.json $DEPLOYPATH
```

I had several problems with it.
One is that it does not start automatically and I have to manually select the *"Deploy Head Commit"* button in the *Git Version Control* panel.
The other is that with these commands I replace all existing files (as the old/delete ones remain in public site) or I replace only a specific file.
So far it was working well but the project will include several thousand files and I want if is possible this part to be done automatically.
Also in public/html... there is a working part of the site that is not part of the current project. I do not dare to do many tests to not break the hosting or damage the other part of the site that is not included in the project.
So far, my guess is that I can use the if-else construction as in java script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$DEPLOYPATH` is `/home/user/public_html/www/`,

```
/usr/bin/rsync --size-only --delete --recursive www/ $DEPLOYPATH
```

will replace files with different sizes (`--size-only`), will delete files in `$DEPLOYPATH` that do not exist in `www/`, and will copy new files that do not exist in `$DEPLOYPATH`. It will do this also for all contained directories (`--recursive`).

To test it, use `--dry-run`. This will not actually copy anything, but write out the files it *would* copy to the terminal.

Comment: Thank you so much! So short and efficient code, it's great. All I have to do is understand why the file .cpanel.yml doesn't start automatically after push changes in repository, but I guess I can contact the hosting provider. Because according to the documentation it should happen automatically when the file .cpanel.yml is available, еven if I fail, this code saves me many hours comparing files. Many thanks!